# Finding unknown matrices that minimize a sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

This problem is about [working with smart-phone accelerometers](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49870/estimate-smartphone-accelerometer-bias/49934#49934).

To calibrate accelerometer, I need to find three unknown matrices $T$, $K$ and $b$ that minimize this sum:
$$\sum_{i=0}^N(|g|^2 - |TK(a_i + B)|^2)^2,$$
where $a_i$'s are known $3×1$ vectors, $|g|$ is a known constant and unknown matrices are:
$$T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t_1 & t_2 \\ 0 & 1 & t_3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},\ K=\begin{bmatrix} k_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & k_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & k_3\end{bmatrix},\ B=\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3\end{bmatrix}.$$

I have read in an article one can solve such problems by Levenberg-Marquardt
(LM) algorithm. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how. Can anyone suggest a solution to this minimization problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. You can solve such problems using [scipy.optimize.root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) which includes  Levenberg-Marquardt (LM) algorithm.